# Indian citizen marriage with european

Tags: indian-citizens

I am in a relation with a polish girl who is working in uk..its a distance relationship since 2011..she came to meet me in india this year ...we are planning to get married in 2016..i want to know the procedure ..on what visa can she come to india to marry me...also would i be able to get a spouse visa for uk after this...we are even ok to move  to some other country in europe.pls help...what are the requirements/eligibility. She is in the uk for more than 2 years now.pls help me with the conditions

Comment: You've asked multiple questions there - what visa she needs, whether you can get a spousal visa, and requirements to move....as per [help] you need to keep questions separate.  It's pedantic, but we're in beta so we need to be super strict. I'm closing it for now, please do edit it to ONE question per post, and it really helps if you can be clear, use sentences and include all relevant detail, as well as the research you've done so far to find out what you need.